# Null pointer exception when running actionPerformed, Java

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null, jframe

been looking in a dead gaze at my code and haven't got anywhere. the program compiles fine, but whenever Play.java runs 'actionPerformed' i get a Null Pointer Exception from the 'AWT-EventQueue-0' thread, or in plain english, when i click the button it throws a NPE. Here's the code (if you want to run it on your own computer you might need to omit some lines on compilation).

Any help is much appreciated in advance

Play.java :-

```
public class Play implements Runnable, ActionListener { 
private MenuFrame menuF;    
private HighScoresFrame hSF;
private GameFrame gameF;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Play program = new Play();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(program);
}

public void run() {
    menuF = new MenuFrame();
    hSF = new HighScoresFrame();
    gameF = new GameFrame();
}

void playGame() {
    System.out.print("running the game!");
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand() == "buttonMenu") {
        menuF.setVisible(true);
        hSF.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand() == "buttonPlayGame") {          
        gameF.setVisible(true);
        menuF.setVisible(false);
        playGame();
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand() == "buttonHighScores") {
        hSF.setVisible(true);
        menuF.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

}

GameFrame.java :-

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 576;
private JFrame game;

public GameFrame() {
    game = new JFrame();

    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT + 20)));

    game.setResizable(false);
    game.setDefaultCloseOperation(game.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.setTitle("COMS11300 Crisis - in game");
    game.pack();
    game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

HighScoresFrame.java :-

```
public class HighScoresFrame extends JFrame {

private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 576;
private int highscores[] = new int[5];
private JFrame hS;

public HighScoresFrame() {
    hS = new JFrame();

    hS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT + 20)));
    hS.getContentPane().add(highscoresLayeredPane());
    hS.setResizable(false);
    hS.setDefaultCloseOperation(hS.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    hS.setTitle("COMS11300 Crisis - High Scores");
    hS.pack();
    hS.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    hS.setVisible(false);
}

JLayeredPane highscoresLayeredPane() {
    JLayeredPane lPane = new JLayeredPane();

    lPane.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    lPane.add(highscoresBackgroundDisplay(), new Integer(0), 0);
    lPane.add(highscoresButtonsDisplay(), new Integer(1), 0);
    lPane.add(highscoresDisplay(), new Integer(2), 0);

    return lPane;
}

ImagePanel highscoresBackgroundDisplay() {
    URL u = this.getClass().getResource("images/background_highscores.png");
    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(u);
    ImagePanel backgroundPanel = new ImagePanel(imgIcon.getImage());

    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    backgroundPanel.setOpaque(true);

    return backgroundPanel;
}

JPanel highscoresButtonsDisplay() {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton menu = new JButton();
    URL uMenu = this.getClass().getResource("images/button_play.png");
    ImageIcon imgMenuIcon = new ImageIcon(uMenu);

    menu.setIcon(imgMenuIcon);
    menu.setBorder(null);
    menu.setActionCommand("buttonMenu");
    menu.addActionListener(new Play());

    buttonPanel.setBounds(730, 355, 280, 200);
    buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
    buttonPanel.add(menu);

    return buttonPanel;
}

String retrieveHighScores() {
    String highscoresString = new String();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        highscoresString += highscores[i];
        highscoresString += "\n";
    }

    return highscoresString;
}

JPanel highscoresDisplay() {
    JPanel scoresPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel scoresLabel = new JLabel(retrieveHighScores(), JLabel.LEFT);

    scoresPanel.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
    scoresPanel.setOpaque(false);
    scoresPanel.add(scoresLabel);

    return scoresPanel;
}
```

}

MenuFrame.java :-

```
public class MenuFrame extends JFrame {

private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 576;
private JFrame menu;

public MenuFrame() {
    menu = new JFrame();

    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT + 20)));
    menu.getContentPane().add(menuLayeredPane());
    menu.setResizable(false);
    menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(menu.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    menu.setTitle("COMS11300 Crisis - Main Menu");
    menu.pack();
    menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    menu.setVisible(true);
}

JLayeredPane menuLayeredPane() {
    JLayeredPane lPane = new JLayeredPane();

    lPane.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    lPane.add(menuBackgroundDisplay(), new Integer(0), 0);
    lPane.add(menuButtonsDisplay(), new Integer(1), 0);

    return lPane;
}

ImagePanel menuBackgroundDisplay() {
    URL u = this.getClass().getResource("images/background_menu.png");
    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(u);
    ImagePanel backgroundPanel = new ImagePanel(imgIcon.getImage());

    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    backgroundPanel.setOpaque(true);

    return backgroundPanel;
}

JPanel menuButtonsDisplay() {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton play = new JButton();
    JButton highScores = new JButton();
    URL uPlay = this.getClass().getResource("images/button_play.png");
    URL uHighScore = this.getClass().getResource("images/button_highscore.png");
    ImageIcon imgPlayIcon = new ImageIcon(uPlay);
    ImageIcon imgHighScoreIcon = new ImageIcon(uHighScore);

    play.setIcon(imgPlayIcon);
    play.setBorder(null);
    play.setActionCommand("buttonPlayGame");
    play.addActionListener(new Play());

    highScores.setIcon(imgHighScoreIcon);
    highScores.setBorder(null);
    highScores.setActionCommand("buttonHighScores");
    highScores.addActionListener(new Play());

    buttonPanel.setBounds(730, 355, 280, 200);
    buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
    buttonPanel.add(play);
    buttonPanel.add(highScores);

    return buttonPanel;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never compare Strings with `==`. Use equals to compare the contents of the strings, rather than the reference.

Then for your NPE : you add a new Play instance as action listener for all your buttons. Each of these Play instance doesn't have any `menuF`, `hSF` or `gameF`, since these variables are initialized by the `run` method.

The MenuFrame and HighScoresFrame constructors should have a `Play` argument, and the `run` method of `Play` should pass `this` as the play argument, so that a unique Play instance is used. This unique play is the one that should be added as action listener.

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick response! note taken on the .equals method. And that fix worked thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops out to me is:

```
e.getActionCommand() == "buttonMenu"
```

should be

```
e.getActionCommand().equals("buttonMenu");
```

As you wish to compare the value of the String, not whether the String objects are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `Play()` objects when you call `.addActionListener`.  You want to pass the current `Play` object as `this` parameter, and use that instead:

```
menuF = new MenuFrame(this);
hSF = new HighScoresFrame(this);
gameF = new GameFrame(this);
```

Inside of `MenuFrame` (for example):

```
private Play play;
public MenuFrame(Play play) {
    this.play = play;
}
```

Inside of `menuButtonsDisplay`:

```
JPanel menuButtonsDisplay() {
    ...
    highScores.addActionListener(this.play);
}
```

Comment: firstly thanks for the super quick response, i implemented what you stated and it works no problems in terms of no exceptions. However on a separate note, when the button is clicked it displays a blank JFrame (i'm assuming it's the default JFrame setting) and doesn't hide 'menuF', any ideas. Thanks again for your time